# Get value of parent record in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I download data from Team Foundation Server that comes out in a parent child format.

| ID | Work Item Type | Remaining Hours | Parent Story | Remaining Hours (Agg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | Story |  | 200 | 8 |
| 568 | Task | 2 | 200 |  |
| 827 | Task | 6 | 200 |  |

I get the first three fields from my data connection.  for the last two, I want to show the story id even for tasks, where the story id  is the closest story id above the record in the list, for tasks, and the story id if the record is a story.

The second field I need to aggregate remaining hours for a tasks in that story.

Assume records will not be sorted and remain in the parent child format.  There can be multiple tasks per story.  I want to do this in power query in excel.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery,

Add a custom column named Parent Story with formula

```
= if [Work Item Type]="Story" then [ID] else null
```

Right click that new column and fill down

Group on Parent Story and sum Remaining Hours.  Add a custom column named Work Item Type with formula = "Story"

Merge that table against the results before the group was done using a Left Outer Join, matching the Work Item Type and Parent Story fields between the tables.  The way I've implemented this required manual code changes in the home...advanced... section.

Expand the hours

Sample code that assumes your 3 column source data is in range Table1.  You can paste the code in PowerQuery in Home...Advanced Editor...

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Work Item Type", type text}, {"Remaining Hours", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Parent Story", each if [Work Item Type]="Story" then [ID] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Parent Story"}),

// group the data to sum hours
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Parent Story"}, {{"TotalHours", each List.Sum([Remaining Hours]), type number}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Work Item Type", each "Story"),

// merge the data back in
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Filled Down",{"Work Item Type", "Parent Story"},#"Added Custom1",{"Work Item Type", "Parent Story"},"Table3",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table3", {"TotalHours"}, {"Remaining Hours (Agg)"})
in #"Expanded Table3"
```

[image]

Alternate code using custom function instead of a merge.

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Work Item Type", type text}, {"Remaining Hours", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Parent Story", each if [Work Item Type]="Story" then [ID] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Parent Story"}),
countem = (i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down" , each [Parent Story]=i) [Remaining Hours]),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "Remaining Hours (Agg)", each if [Work Item Type] = "Task" then null else countem([Parent Story] ))
in #"Added Custom1"
```